# Dock won't go back to primary screen

Tags: dock

So I have a setup as shown on the image, the top screen being a monitor (with a powered USB-C cable if that makes any difference), and the bottom is  a MacBook. As shown, top display is my primary display. However, when I mess up and move the mouse to the bottom of the MacBook screen, the dock goes there and doesn't wanna go back no matter what I do. Reboot will fix it. If I change the dock position to left/right, it'll go to top screen. If I move the bottom screen to NOT be under the top screen, dock goes back to top screen (bottom position). Does anyone know any way to fix this? If it makes a difference, I'm running 2019 13'' MacBook Pro with the latest Catalina update (10.15.2 (19C57))

[image]

Comment: System Prefs>Mission Control> Displays have separate Spaces… on or off?

Comment: @Tetsujin it's on

Comment: OK. Just needed to check. Dock will not go to any edge *between* screens. You can check this most easily with displays side by side. Dock at the bottom will swap screens as expected, on either side, it will not.

Comment: Oh okay, that's a shame. So I gotta reboot every time I mess it up